# How to have tree like structure in html combo box

Tags: css, html, forms, user-interface

i want to have a combo box like element in my page. For that i am thinking to use html select tag. On selecting any element of the combo box, i want the list of items to expand (Just like folder tree). How to do that?

```
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
<option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
<option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
```

On selecting Hot bread it should expand dynamically & show types of breads.

Comment: search for expanding tree, or dynamic tree on google, you'll get some examples like this
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/navigate1.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be done with **`optgroup`**, example: ["la liste déroulante", visible option "France"](http://openweb.eu.org/IMG/article26/champs.html#select).
But loading/completing it dynamically will probably cause accessibility problems... And an annoying problem with optgroup, by design, is that it groups options and has a label but this label can't be selected itself (in the above example you can choose a country but not a continent).

A **serie of `select`** was often seen: choose an option in a first select, click button "Choose continent", following select get populated depending on what you chose in the first select, click second button "Choose country" and get your result (or populate a third select, etc).

A **tree** is far more versatile (it's a bunch of lists and links, same HTML structure than a sitemap or a navigation list (of lists)) but it's harder to implement it. A very good example based on jQuery UI can be found at: [jQtest by Hans Hillen](http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_tree).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example which worked for me:

```
http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html?m=1
```